# Double IF condition based on another column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need to calculate the days between two dates.
There's also a condition based on a column (special) so if 'special' is yes then 'reaction time' should be empty/null, if 'special' is no it returns the days.

The problem is that sometimes the days beetween two dates are negative values and for these I want to display 0. I.e every value < 0 should read as 0.

This is where I've got so far, but I can't get everything <0 to display as 0.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M-KUin-OhECcahugpFf8KKSadVfYytJo7Mj9A-58CJg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case:

```
=IF(C2="no";max(B2-A2;0);"")
```

and also double if is possible:

```
=IF(C2="no";if(B2-A2<0;0;B2-A2);"")
```